# Yarn and Webpack Encore configuration in Symfony 4.1 project

Tags: webpack, yarnpkg, symfony4, webpack-encore

### Introduction

I am trying out `Symfony 4.1` + `Yarn` + `Webpack Encore` on a project that requires file upload. To do that i chose `OneUpUploaderBundle` with `Blueimp jquery file upload` frontend.

But getting a bit stomped by amount of configuration that is needed 
as oposed to *old scool* approach to add `CSS` and `JavaScript`
wherever they are needed - yet without of advantages of package 
management.

Of course updating dependencies easyly with package manager 
does come with a price. But when after initial configuration 
build compiles it is easy afterwards or suposed to be easy.

### Problem

I would like to be able to upload files using previously mentioned combination of libraries. I am looking for correct config.

At the moment build does not compile - i get an error!

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
This dependency was not found:
* jquery-ui/ui/widget in ./node_modules/blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js
```

As you ccan see from attached code i tried to provide alias for `jquery-ui/ui/widget`, yet it did not result in found package.

Also, there is no package `jquery-ui/ui/widget` in Yarn directory, but
there is `jquery.ui.widget` which i tried to require unsucessfully.

### Code

**Webpack.config.js**

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

Encore
    // directory where all compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')

    // what's the public path to this directory (relative to your project's document root dir)
    .setPublicPath('/build')

    // allow legacy applications to use $/jQuery as a global variable
    .autoProvidejQuery()

    // empty the outputPath dir before each build
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

    // will output as web/build/app.js
    .addEntry('app', './assets/js/main.js')
    .addEntry('blueimp', './assets/js/blueimp.js')

    .addStyleEntry('global', './assets/css/global.scss')
    .addStyleEntry('admin', './assets/css/admin.scss')

    .addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        // copies to {output}/static
        { from: './assets/static', to: 'static' }
    ]))

    // allow sass/scss files to be processed
    .enableSassLoader(function(sassOptions) {},
        {
            resolveUrlLoader: false
        }
    )

    .autoProvideVariables({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        'jquery.ui.widget': 'jquery-ui/ui/widget'
    })

    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

// create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
// .enableVersioning()
;

// export the final configuration
module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

**Package.json**

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.20.1",
        "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "blueimp-file-upload": "^9.22.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "jquery.ui.widget": "^1.10.3",
        "jstree": "^3.3.5",
        "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```
// loads the jquery package from node_modules
var $ = window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

// or you can include specific pieces
require('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap');
```

**blueimp.js**

```
'use strict';

// add upload
require('blueimp-file-upload/css/jquery.fileupload.css');
require('blueimp-file-upload/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css');

require('jquery/dist/jquery.js');
require('jquery.ui.widget/jquery.ui.widget.js');
require('blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js');
require('blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js');
```

### Thank you

Thank you for your coments and answers.

Comment: afaik `autoProvideVariables()` doesn't define aliases @Rikijs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was [adding an alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) directly on the web pack config. Notice I also required the `path` module.

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
var path = require('path');

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');


Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // ...
;

var config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();

config.resolve.alias = {
    'jquery-ui/ui/widget': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/jquery.ui.widget/jquery.ui.widget.js')
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: Thank you! Your changes to configuration produces build without an error.